# Select all layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, select, remove

In the previous versions of QGIS, to select all layers in the 'layer panel' and then remove them, I used 'CTRL + A'.

In QGIS 3.22 this is not possible and to delete multiple layers I have to select them one by one and then click on the remove button. Is there a way to select all the layers quickly?

Comment: I don't know the keyboard shortcut, but you can select multiple by dragging, or by using Shift + click.

Comment: Shift+click is a good solution  thanks